# How to do 2-legged OAuth2 authentication using httr

Tags: r, httr, uservoice

I am currently implmenting OAuth authentication from R to UserVoice. I am using httr package to do regular OAuth2 authentication. It works well, but I need to go and enter my credentials in browser to get the token. I can cache the token and use it later, but I would like to avoid this hassle as I want to deploy this script to a server.

As far as I figured out, there is a way to avoid entering my login/password in browser if I use 2-legged-authentication instead of 3-legged-authentication. But I cannot find how to change the default httr package behavior to do 2-legged-authentication.

I also found that there is a service login support in httr, but as I understand it works only if you have a service account (as in Google). I don't have such an account in UserVoice. But I know that UserVoice supports 2-legged-authentication.

What parameters in httr should I change to do 2-legged-authentication? Or maybe there is another package I should use that support 2-legged-authentication?

Thanks.